# Auto fill a total row in an Excel table

Tags: excel

Is it possible to quickly select one formula for all of the cells in a total row of an Excel table? I have about 10 tables with 10 columns each and I want to set the total row formula to be sum of the row above, but right now I have to manually select sum for each cell.

If I copy and paste from one cell to its horizontal neighbors, the table referencing causes all the neighbors to sum the original column. If I set the formula manually using cell references (b1:b10), then those references get broken if the table expands. So I'd like a way to sum the entire row, and have that formula apply across all cells in the total row.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of copy/paste, drag the formula from the first column to the other columns. That method will automatically update the sum formula to the relative column reference.

Answer (score -1):

So I pulled up excel because this made me curious and here is what I was able to do...

I dropped a series in Row 13 (1 - 20) starting with A13 as 1 and to the right up to twenty.

After that I selected the row 13 label to highlight the entire row, and in the formula's tab of excel I hit auto-sum.

the formula dropped the correct sum in column XFD...now, if you only have 20 columns you may not want to scroll 3 miles to the right...but I suppose you could just hide the extra columns and you wouldn't ever have to worry about editing the formulas unless your table got way out of hand.

```
=SUM(A13:XFC13)
```